# Alias to show a subfolder's file counts

Tags: shell, alias

I made an alias **lfwc** to show current folder's file count, I also want to show a sub folder's file count, so i made the following:

```
alias wcdir="cd $1;lfwc;cd .."
```

It did not work as expected.

Comment: Aliases don't take arguments, write a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since aliases don't take arguments, you have to use a function:

```
wcdir() {
    cd "$1"
    lfwc
    cd ..
}
```

Comment: which file should this function in,so I can call it elsewhere?

Comment: The same file you put your aliases in.

Comment: Reverted your edit. The `function` keyword shouldn't be necessary, and is non-standard.

Comment: @metaphy If you give `function` keyword, then `()` are optional and if you give `{}` then `function` keyword is optional. However, the way barmar showed you is specified in POSIX and all Bourne like shells support it, so use that method.